# Check if correct input in C

Tags: c

This is my program.

```
reprocess:

    printf("Enter number: 1,2,3 ");

    if(scanf("%d%c", &preproc, &term)!= 2 || term!= '\n' ){
        printf("Invalid Input");
        goto reprocess;


    }else{

        if ((preproc==1) || (preproc==2) || (preproc==3)){
        printf("Correct Input\n");

        }else{
        printf("Invalid Input %d \n", preproc);
        goto reprocess;

        }
    }
```

Why is it that if I input a string it doesn't stop from looping? Please guide me.

Comment: You explicitly wrote that if they input a string then `goto reprocess;` . What did you expect?

Comment: @AdamSinclair huh? This code only prints `Invalid Input` (possibly followed by a number), or `Correct Input`.

Comment: This is just some sort of an input checker.

Comment: What do you exaclty mean by "it doesn't stop from looping" ?

Comment: I just tried your code, it works for me

Comment: Enter number: 1,2,3 Invalid Input gets printed repeatedly.

Comment: can you show your declaration of preproc and term?

Comment: Does it have something to do with my compiler?

Comment: ` int preproc;
 char term;`  this is what I declared them as when I tried your code

Comment: that is how I declared it too. @KeithNicholas

Comment: ok, try changing it to \r  instead of \n and see what happens

Comment: dude what do u want? if you enter string your code will repeat the loop and that's what you programmed ! do u expect it to change is to integer and quit ?!]

Comment: See [**printing-the-input-of-char-within-a-loop-in-c**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924172/printing-the-input-of-char-within-a-loop-in-c), You need to flush the input buffer. And I don't think you are doing that with `term`

Comment: the thing is if the user enters a  String or Int it should ask for another input until the user inputs eithet 1,2,3.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if(scanf("%d%c", &preproc, &term)!= 2 || term!= '\n' ){
    printf("Invalid Input\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]");//this will skip the input when there is a non-numeric input.
    goto reprocess;
}else{
```