# Printing the input of char within a loop in C

Tags: c

Suppose char c is an input of single character from user.

```
if (c != 'A' && c != 'B' &&  c != 'C' && c != 'D') {
    int t = 1;
    while (t = 1) {
    printf("%c is an invalid input. Valid cases are A-D.\n", c);
    scanf( "%c", &input); /* Space for taking care of whitespace */
    c = lowToUp(c); /* If c is lowercase, convert to uppercase */
    if (c == 'A' || c == 'B' || c == 'C' || c == 'D') {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to display this error message and continue the loop until user inputs valid char value.

The loop itself is fine but the output is not. If I enter X,

```
X is an invalid input. Valid cases are A-D.

 is an invalid input. Valid cases are A-D.
```

The invisible \n after the actual value of c has not bothered me in any other part of my program except this one.

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: You are entering the loop twice.  Once for input `X` and once for `\n`.

Comment: c never changes in the loop (except for upper-casing) as new input is put into "input". Are you sure this is code you're running?

Comment: Yes, that is the exact code I ran for the result.

Comment: `while (int t = 1)` ... it certainly isn't.

Comment: Already fixed it. Wouldn't even have been able to run it otherwise would I.

Comment: @mafso good point. That is legal in C++ but not in C. Perhaps OP is not using the compiler he thinks he is

Comment: I fixed that before I ran the code to get the result displayed in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

After each `scanf`, you need to flush the input buffer. E.g.:

```
int c;
....
scanf (....)
do { c = getchar (); } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);     /* flush input buffer */
```

Comment: It now only seems to display the second part of my original result, the one with \n instead of c.

Comment: @whdPdnjs you probably have data left in the buffer from some input earlier in your code

Comment: Just found that it actually doesn't read in the char value before \n at all, so even if I enter the valid value in second loop and onwards, the loop is ongoing.

Comment: @whdPdnjs you probably have data left in the buffer from some input earlier in your code

Answer (score 0):

As you said in `/* Space for taking care of whitespace */`, a space inside the format string will consume any number of whitespaces. You didn't put any, however.

```
scanf(" %c",&input);
     //^ notice the space is inside the string, not before it like you did
```

Comment: That was done because there was a certain, specific problem between the editor and the server that with scanf("%c", &input);, the value taken in will be just \n for some reason unknown by others working on the same project nor the instructors. Removing the space would return \n no matter what I type in thereby making the loop impenetrable.